# Get multiple results from db

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working on a fairly large project in (object oriented) PHP which includes a webshop where users can buy products and additional licenses and services. Purchasing is a four step process:

- **Step 1**: User chooses a product, and `product_id` is passed to *step 2*
- **Step 2**: Fetching and outputting all license types based on `product_id`, passing `product_id` on to *step 3*
- **Step 3**: Fetching and outputting all services based on `product_id`, in a form with checkboxes named `services[$service_id]`

So now, on the checkout on `step 4`, I fetch the correct products and licenses from the database, but I also have to get the correct services from the db based on the services array, and calculate the price to output. At last, I'll have to assign the services array to the Smarty template.

How would the most suitable way to do this be? I really hope that someone is kind enough to help me out here, as I'm having a very hard time trying to make this work.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is the webshop a seperate ecommerce package you are integrating or is it also a bespoke component of the large project?

Comment: It is a custom coded webshop module for my framework. Why are you asking? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
    $resulter = array();
    $i = 0;
     foreach($product_id as $value) {
     $query = "Select  FROM products WHERE product_id = $value"; 

     Your execution code

    $resulter[$i] = $result;   //$result could be a assoc array
    $i++
     }
```

And If I ware you I would i would use a multidimensional array like I shown above.

Comment: Thanks man! I made something similar myself: http://pastebin.com/d48RuLR8 - But how would I assign this to the template? (smarty)

Comment: [link](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)

Take a look at the Smarty Foreace it thik that the syntax of was 

 {foreach from=SMARTYVAR item=i}
  <li>Discount: {$i.discount}</li>
{/foreach}

Comment: Give me an give me more information as I can see you need to assign only the $service array. So try assign like this like this
> PHP
> foreach($service[$i] as $value){
> $smarty->assign(SMARTYVAR, $service[$i])


and after that One foreach handle in the template and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Something like a JOIN on the 'products' table and 'licences' table using the 'product_id' field to make the join.

An example query would be something like:

```
SELECT <required_fields_here>
FROM products
JOIN licences ON licences.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE product_id = <product_id_here>
```

Note that in the SELECT section you can select fields from both 'products' and 'licences' tables, you just need to prefix with the table and a dot e.g. 'product.product_id'

I think you will need to be more specific if you need further help. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I don't really get the idea of joins. What do they exactly do?

Comment: I linked to an article about joins in my answer that will explain it better than I can here.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the problem is not to get the products and the licenses. I already get them in another query. The problem is that I have an array of service_id's which I need to fetch from the database.